# CCShaderCache gone in Cocos2d 1.1. Use what instead?

Tags: cocos2d-iphone

The CCShaderCache class is gone from Cocos2D v.1.1. I don't see mention of it in the 1.1 docs either. Any idea what to use instead?

It appears that the CCShaderCache class is in fact included in v.2.0., just not v.1.1.

Comment: Why you are not using Cocos2d 2.0 ?

Comment: I am updating an existing project and was under the impression that certain elements would not be supported.

Comment: It appears that the CCShaderCache class is in fact included in v.2.0., just not v.1.1.

Answer (score 0):

CCShaderCache manages shader programs. It's only available in cocos2d 2.x because shader programs are only available in OpenGL ES 2.0 which cocos2d 2.x uses.

Cocos2d v1.x however is using OpenGL ES 1.1, so there are no shaders. There is nothing you can use instead.

I do have to wonder, if you're updating an existing project how come you're now "missing" the CCShaderCache class? It was never in any of the v1.x (or v0.x) branches.